# WPF How to use Windows Dialogs with Pixelsense as Touchevents don't fire mouseclick-events

Tags: wpf, touch, pixelsense

I recently started to develop a Pixelsense application when I came to a general problem using touch events as input. Common .net Dialogs such as SaveFileDialog, OpenFileDialog etc. from the Win32 namespace don't work using touch technology as touch events don't fire mouse click events.

Is there any way to invoke the mouseclick for a touchevent?

Maybe there is a general solution such that all touch events get routed automatically?

I'd like to avoid to re-implement all the common dialogs on my own just adding the touchevent.

Any links or ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you really expecting the users of your program to operate a standard file dialog by touch input? I would be quite irritated.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, you will have to re-implement the dialogs in a touch-appropriate way

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your goal btw you can find some interesting information about the windows input in these two articles:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754010.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317321(v=vs.85)

Dialogs on a Surface SDK 2.0 running on a PixelSense device will never came out this is by design.
So if you really need some dialogs you need to implement it from starch.
Even if you are able to show up dialogs (because you are running your PixelSense app in a standard W7) and these doesn't get touch events (I never tested it I assume that your statement is right) you will need to reimplement it.

Now my question is: Do you really need dialog boxes in a nui app?? If your anserw is yes well, my advice is to think in a NUI way: scatterview, scatterviewitem, librarycontainers, dragdropsvi...

hth
-g